# Nome das colunas no xml de retorno do web service

Tags: entity-framework, web-service, linq, expressões-lambda

Essa linha me dá esse erro:

```
if (db.T_TarefaParceiro.Max(p => p.IDTarefaParceiro) != null)
```

O erro

```
The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
```

Como o campo IDTarefaParceiro é uma chave primária, ele não pode ser nullable. Como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolvi assim:

```cs
if (db.T_TarefaParceiro.Max(p => (int?)p.IDTarefaParceiro) != null)
```